# sql - find duplicates on second order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a color table t1 with data like below, sorted by sn

```
select * from t1 order by sn
+---+-------+
|sn |color  |
+---+-------+
|25 |Brown  |
|29 |Brown  |
|33 |Blue   |
|37 |Red    |
|42 |Green  |
|46 |Yellow |
|49 |Red    |
|53 |Red    |
|57 |Red    |
|61 |Blue   |
|65 |Red    |
|69 |Pink   |
+---+-------+
```

I need to find 2 or more adjacent rows having same color when sorted by sn.

```
|25 |Brown  |
|29 |Brown  |

|49 |Red    |
|53 |Red    |
|57 |Red    |
```

I tried something like the lag() function in SQL, but that gets only 2 adjacent rows.
I'm not able to expand the solution to address it in a generic way.
Can this be solved.

```
select sn, color, lag(color) over(order by sn) prev_color from t1
```

Comment: you need lag and lead in a subquery and to test if there is a match with either in the outer query

Comment: Which database do you really use? Most probably not MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle. Solution might depend on that.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use

Comment: I use postgressql, but the solution is portable right.

Comment: not necessarily portable.  for instance, lag in mysql requires version 8; older version do not support it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A row should be returned if its `color` is the same as the previous or the next row:

```
SELECT sn, color
FROM (  
  SELECT *,
         LAG(color) OVER (ORDER BY sn) prev_color,
         LEAD(color) OVER (ORDER BY sn) next_color
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE color IN (prev_color, next_color);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3FpiTXji).

Comment: Ok.. this works for 2 or 3 duplicates.. how to extend it for n duplicates?

Comment: I tested and found that it works for more duplicates..  thank you!

Comment: Is there a way I could add duplicate number 2 or 3 as another column?.

Comment: If you need portability for Oracle you need t change the `*` to `sn, color`, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/WDsK5BTm.    For MySQL this query works (8+)

Comment: @stack0114106 use ROW_NUMBER() also: https://dbfiddle.uk/N_HXHoky

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple join:

```
select t.sn, t.color from t1 t
left join (
  select
     sn,
     lag(color) over(order by sn) as lag,
     lead(color) over(order by sn) as lead
  from t1 
) l on t=sn = l.sn
where t.color = l.lag or t.color=l.lead
```